# How to Properly Set the State of a CheckBox Control in OnNavigatedTo

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am having a problem with setting the state of a control on my page. For instance, I have a checkbox that I would like to set its checked state depending on its value previously, which I can do just fine, but the Checked click event runs every time I do this. In this case, it is a problem because I have a CustomMessageBox which always shows up. This occurs regardless of whether the page is navigated to from another page, or if the page resumes from tomb stoning. How can I get around this issue to visually show the state in the view but not run the event associated with it?

Page.xaml

```
<CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked">
                        <CheckBox.Content>
                            <TextBlock Text="checked or not checked" FontSize="20" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                        </CheckBox.Content>
                    </CheckBox>
```

Page.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        //Set the checked state of the Checkbox when page is navigated to
        if (Settings.CheckBoxEnabled.Value == true)
            CheckBox.IsChecked = true;
        else
            CheckBox.IsChecked = false;

    }

private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var cb = sender as CheckBox;

        if (cb.IsChecked.HasValue)
        {
            if (cb.IsChecked.Value == true)
            {
                Settings.CheckBoxEnabled.Value = true;

                //..code that calls another method which also shows a CustomMessageBox
            }
        }
    }

    private void CheckBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var cb = sender as CheckBox;

        if (cb.IsChecked.HasValue)
        {
            if (cb.IsChecked.Value == false)
            {
                Settings.CheckBoxEnabled.Value = false;

                CustomMessageBox messageBox = new CustomMessageBox()
                {
                    Caption = "\n" + "Checkbox change!",
                    Message = "\n" + "You have changed the state of the checkbox." + "\n",
                    LeftButtonContent = "OK"
                };

                messageBox.Dismissed += (s1, e1) =>
                {
                    switch (e1.Result)
                    {
                        case CustomMessageBoxResult.LeftButton:
                            //Do nothing
                            break;
                        case CustomMessageBoxResult.None:
                            //Do nothing
                            break;
                        default:
                            //Do nothing
                            break;
                    }
                };

                messageBox.Show();
            }
        }
    }
```

My implementation works great except for the issues described above. How can I get around these events firing when the page is navigated to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want event fired every time CheckBox is checked/unchecked, but you want it to fire when user clicks - then subscribe to CheckBox.Click. The code could look like this:

```
// in page Constuctor or in XAML:
myCheckBox.Click += myCheckbox_Click;

private void myCheckbox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if (myCheckBox.IsChecked == true)
   {
      //do for check
   }
   else
   {
      //do for uncheck
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A way(Heck) to manage Checked/unchecked events on Navigation is using a global int variable on the page

just Declare a global variable on the page cs class

```
    int CheckFlag = 0;
```

now, in the checked event

```
private void CycleTileCheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(checkFlag!=0)
        {
        var cb = sender as CheckBox;
        if (cb.IsChecked.HasValue)
        {
            if (cb.IsChecked.Value == true)
            {
                Settings.CheckBoxEnabled.Value = true;
                //..code that calls another method which also shows a CustomMessageBox
            }
        }
      }
      else
      {checkFlag=1;}
    }
```

Don't forget to make it 0 on On NavigatedFrom event.